# Next.js Page Misrouting Public Folder?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My page file is attempting to find the public folder in the wrong place. I have the follow code:

```
// The page.js file:

export default function Page() {

    const image = "images/image.png"

    return <div>
        <img src={image} />
    </div>
}
```

The image failed to load.

I expected it to grab image from `localhost:3000/images/image.png`, where it exists, however when I check console, it is trying to GET to `localhost:3000/projects/images/image.png`.

Folder layout:

```
/pages
    /projects
        page.js
/public
    /images
        image.png
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Try adding a forward slash at the beginning, like so `/images/image.png`.

Comment: As @ajmnz mentioned, you need to add the forward slash to the source string, see https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving.

Comment: @ajmnz Such a simple fix! I spent hours trying to fix this, can't believe I didn't try something so simple. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Serenacula Np! Next time you encounter a problem, try first browsing the docs, they are pretty good and cover a wide range of topics and use cases.